# Formula for excel (return largest number for subtraction of different cells and which cells were used for answer)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to return the largest number for the difference of different cells - ie, return largest number after computing **a1**-**b1**, **a1**-**c1**, **b1**-**c1**. Assuming

```
a1=3 
b1=2
c1=1
```

then number returned is 2 (as `a1=3 minus c1=1 gives 2`). I also want to be able to tell that the answer came specifically from **a1**-**c1**, or whatever the case may have been.  Actual amount of cells is far higher than the three given, so doing each equation in a separate cell is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The following User Defined Function *(UDF)* will handle any number of cells *(not just three)*:

```
Public Function MaxDiff(rIN As Range) As String
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, WhichOnes As String
    Dim v As Double, diff As Double
    Dim difftemp As Double

    diff = 0
    For Each r1 In rIN
        v = r1.Value
        For Each r2 In rIN
            difftemp = Abs(v - r2.Value)
            If difftemp > diff Then
                diff = difftemp
                WhichOnes = r1.Address(0, 0) & "-" & r2.Address(0, 0)
            End If
        Next r2
    Next r1
    MaxDiff = CStr(diff) & " -> " & WhichOnes
End Function
```

It gives both the maximum value of the absolute difference of cells in the range as well as the address of those cells.  For example:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=MaxDiff(A1:Z1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

Three formulas:

Since the max difference will always be the difference between the max number and the min number to find the difference:

```
=MAX($A$1:$A$10)-MIN($A$1:$A$10)
```

To find the Addresses:

MAX:

```
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=MAX($A$1:$A$10)),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=MAX($A$1:$A$10)),1))
```

MIN:

```
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=MIN($A$1:$A$10)),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=MIN($A$1:$A$10)),1))
```

If you want them all in ones cell like @Gary'sStudent simply concatenate them:

```
=MAX($A$1:$A$10)-MIN($A$1:$A$10) & "->" & ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=MAX($A$1:$A$10)),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=MAX($A$1:$A$10)),1)) & "-" & ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=MIN($A$1:$A$10)),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$A$10)/($A$1:$A$10=MIN($A$1:$A$10)),1))
```

[image]